# Spring data/mongoDB - NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DBRef

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I use this dependency in my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and with this dependency tho mongoDB diver artefacts are in my project:

```
mongodb-driver-3.4.1.jar and
mongodb-driver.core-3.4.1.jar
```

both do have a package **com.mongodb**.
I get the following exception:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DBRef.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/DB;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my collection:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
```

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

```
@Document(collection = "MyCollection")
public class MyCollection {

@Id
private String id;
@DBRef
private User user;

}
```

[image: Spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb]

Comment: I have no clue, but on top u gave dependency with version and on screenshot there is no version added?

Comment: because version is defined in parent- POM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both legacy driver(`2.x`) and new driver(`3.x`) have same package (`com.mongodb`)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.DBRef.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/DB;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/2.14.x/src/main/com/mongodb/DBRef.java#L67

Notice the first argument is `DB` which is constructor in 2.x driver and is removed from 3.x version.

So it looks like your project is still referencing 2.x driver version.